# time out error while running scraping script of php

Tags: php, time, max, execution

I used following things here for script but no result.
This lines used by me in script.

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", "10000"); ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M'); error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

?

Comment: Yes I did it but no result....
Actually it is data scrapping script....